# How to extract pages from PDF naming them with a field on the page in terminal

Tags: bash, pdf, terminal, pdf-generation, ocr

Every week I run payroll using ADP. They export all the employee pay stubs to a single PDF in seemingly random order.

I'm currently running `pdfseparate all_pay_stubs.pdf %d.pdf` to separate each pay stub (page) into a separate PDF.

The problem is that each file is named by the page number: `1.pdf, 2.pdf, ... n.pdf`. This makes it difficult to find which file belongs to which employee.

I want to pull the employees name from the pay stub and use that as the PDF name:
`john\ smith.pdf, jane\ doe.pdf, ... name.pdf`

How can I do this in terminal?

Comment: Tools like `pdftotext` or `pdfgrep` allow you to extract text from PDF files. However, we cannot help you without some examples. Show use two or three PDF pages.